# QML Settings Type does not have effect in my app

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have decided to use `Qt.labs.settings 1.0` to save the state of my window in this manner:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    // Main configuration section for the application window
    id: mainwindow
    visible: true // Needed if loading from c++.

    property string accentchosen: "#F4511E"

    height: Units.dp(600)
    minimumHeight:  Units.dp(500)
    maximumHeight: Units.dp(1200)
    width: Units.dp(800)
    minimumWidth: Units.dp(300)
    maximumWidth: Units.dp(1080)

    Settings {
        id: settings
        property alias x: mainwindow.x
        property alias y: mainwindow.y
        property alias width: mainwindow.width
        property alias height: mainwindow.height
        property alias accentchosen: mainwindow.accentchosen
    }
}
```

This code will result in my application starting on the `x` and `y` position it was last on, but its `width` and `height` do not seem to follow their last state, instead they keep being `600`x`800`.

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html) the second time, and each subsequent time after that, it should remember its state. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you set [application identifIers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html#application-identifiers)? Even if it is not clearly stated in the docs, they are mandatory for the settings to be persistent. It could also be a bug: it works perfectly fine on my OSX installation.

Comment: It works on android and windows as well, providing the app identifiers are set.

Comment: BTW does this code really work? ApplicationWindow is part of the Controls module and you don't seem to import that.

Comment: @ddriver It must work on Windows with the identifiers, yeah. It still works in my OSX without them. Probably something different in the implementation. As for the code, I've missed a line in the edit. OP didn't added any import in the original code.

Comment: Yeah guys I did not add the includes, my bad. I am using as can you see (well more accurately I am testing)  the qml material design module by papyros and I think the whole reason is the fact that width and height is not a constant value but is given by the expression `Units.dp`